# Fixing a broken X initialization

Tags: x11, startup

#### Here are the symptoms:

On reboot of my Fedora 14 system, I get to the Fedora loading screen progress bar. The system seems to progress normally, then the nvidia logo flashes, a wait cursor shows, then it kicks back to Fedora loading bar. This flashes across the screen about 4 or 5 more times before kicking me back to the completed fedora progress bar. At this point it does NOT start the GUI.

#### What I can do:

I can <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>  (or <kbd>F3</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>) to get to a login shell. In the login shell I can run the `startx` command and I get to my GUI, but with limited functionality (I.e. my network devices are not initialized)

#### What I think I broke:

I had mistakenly deleted the `/tmp/.X0-lock` file on experiencing some other odd behavior with my X server (odd behavior = starting a gnome gui program and receiving an error I can't recall now about the X server not being valid and the program never starting)

#### Question

This is now occurring on every reboot. How can I troubleshoot the X initialization and fix it so that the Fedora GUI starts auto-magically as it did before?

Comment: It seems unlikely that deleting something in `/tmp` has caused your problem, as these are temporary files, and deleted on reboot anyway. Did you change anything else? If you can run startx directly, as least X is not broken.

Comment: Deleting a file in `/tmp` shouldn't cause any harm. Some systems even delete all the contents of `/tmp` at boot time, or store `/tmp` in volatile memory. It is important not to have files with bad permissions though; what does `ls -ld /tmp /tmp/.X* /tmp/.X*/*` show? More generally, there is probably a clue in the X log file. This file is at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` on Debian, might be in a different place on Fedora. Please post the contents of that file if you find it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank your for the comments. The logs were found, but I decided to take a more drastic option and reinstall X. From one of the login shell's I did a `yum reinstall xorg-x11-server-Xorg.x86_64` and after a reboot, that seemed to fix the issue. I know that wasnt exactly *fixing* the problem, but it worked for me.